# How to set a pivot point while doing rotate animation using object animator in xml in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using property animation to rotate a fragment when it goes off screen. Following is my animator xml code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="rotationY"
    android:valueFrom="-70"
    android:valueTo="0" >
</objectAnimator>
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="500"
    android:propertyName="alpha"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="1" >
</objectAnimator>
```

I want to rotate with the central point of the left edge as the pivot. How to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can add the:

```
android:transformPivotX and
android:transformPivotY
```

values to the object you want to animate in the layout XML where you created the object
(Eg. `android:transformPivotX="0dp"`)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use `View.PivotX()` and `View.PivotY()` for that.

Comment: Note: view.getPivotX/Y and view.setPivotX/Y are only available api 11+